# PHP user input through HTML tag

Tags: php

I just started with learning PHP, video tutorials on youtube and stuff, and I can't figure out why the following doesn't work.

I have two files, one `index.php` and the other `secondpage.php`

The contents of `index.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="secondpage.php">
        <input name="name" type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the contents of `secondpage.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Second page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            echo $name;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect that clicking submit on the first page would just output out whatever text I typed in in the input box, but I just get a blank page. Why?

Comment: You're missing `$name=$_POST['name'];` ;) didn't that tutorial mention that?

Comment: And always define a method attribute for your form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so the "POST" is like an array(or should I say dictionary?) indexed by whatever the variable name in the original page was?

Comment: Maybe the tutorial was using register globals :P

Comment: You could say, sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It seems everybody is just copying your comment. Which is wrong as it should be `$_GET` :-)

Comment: @jeroen Augh!! you're right! More Espresso please. I'll blame it on Monday ;)

Comment: Just to be politically correct and to add to my first comment; `<form>` defaults to GET when omitted. Use `method = "post"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, at least all answers are not wrong any more ;-)

Comment: Why exactly am I getting downvoted? :p I understand this isn't exactly a brilliant question, so there's no upvote but why the downvotes?

Comment: @jeroen There is "one" that isn't correct; it's still at "0" ups and no DVs. Should have been `echo $_GET['name'];` then it would have most likely worked.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Probably because of the lack of research effort; a simple search for `php form submit` or the php manual would have given you the answer. Even w3schools has this one right...  I would have downvoted for that reason if there hadn't been any upvoted answers (with upvoted answers you cannot delete your question any more).

Comment: @Sabyasachi [You're welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365722/php-user-input-through-html-tag/25366105#comment39552138_25365722). I believe you have enough answers below (and information) to get you going on your way to success; including mine. *Cheers*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually get the value first.  Also, you need the correct method in your form tag.

`<form>` defaults to GET if the method isn't defined, therefore use `method="post"`.

HTML:

```
<form action="secondpage.php" method="post">
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
            echo $name;
        ?>
```

That will do it.

EDIT:  Didn't mean to paoch this answer.  In the time it took to write it, like 4 comments came in saying the same thing.

Comment: "POST" is like an array(or should I say dictionary?) indexed by whatever the variable name in the original page was?

Comment: Was this just copied from the first comment? Because it's wrong, without a `method` attribute, the method will be GET.

Comment: *"Didn't mean to paoch this answer."* - Don't sweat it ;) I'll even +1

Comment: Wait a sec. OP left out the method which defaults to GET.

Comment: First - yes, POST IS an array of objects that can be accessed by name.  And also, jeroen is correct.  You need to add the method attribute to your form tag.

Comment: You should make an edit to that effect, since you were first to answer.

Comment: Thanks, Fred.  I need to remember to me more thorough with my answers.

Answer (score 2):

Because $name is not set when you click submit.

To access the input you have to add an method to your form (POST).

```
<form action="secondpage.php" method="post">
```

And than to access your input on the second page:

```
    <?php 
        echo $_POST['name'];
    ?>
```

Tip: turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

*You see,* when you omit the form method, **it defaults to GET** and since you're not telling PHP on how to retrieve the variable, it doesn't know how to process it.

Had error reporting been ON, it would have most likely thrown an
`Notice: Undefined variable: name in...(path to file) on line X` error message.
*Consult my note on error reporting below.*

Had you done `echo $_GET['name'];` it would have worked.

Or

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;
```

However, if you explicitly use a "post" form method, then you must include it in your form.

I.e.: `method="post"`

then using `echo $_POST['name'];`

or

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
```

***Yet***, using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) would be an additional variable handling function to use.

---

***Error reporting:***

Also, error reporting is important when writing code to outline errors found; if any.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

---

***Foot/sidenote:***

If omitting the method and that GET is what you want to use, then that is entirely acceptable. Otherwise, use the POST method along with the examples as shown.

More information on forms can be seen by visiting the PHP.net's Website:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php**

---

You should also be made aware of (XSS) Cross-site scripting.

Here are a few links to read up on:

- **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting**
- **http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/**
- **http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/**

You can further your research by using "XSS injection php" (and/or adding " forms $_GET and $_POST") as keywords in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use secondpage.php as

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Second page</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <?php 
        echo $_POST['name'];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```